# How can I use a condition to set a variable value in Ansible?

Tags: ansible

I have two variables: `a`, `b`.

I want to assign a value to a variable `c` based on which: `a` or `b` contains greater numerical value.

This what I tried:

```
- set_fact:
    c: "test1"
  when: a <= b

- set_fact:
    c: "test2"
  when: b <= a
```

Look like it always sets `c` to `test1` not `test2`.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

- Using `if-else` expression:

  ```
  - set_fact:
      c: "{{ 'test1' if (a >= b) else 'test2' }}"
  ```
- Using ternary operator:

  ```
  - set_fact:
      c: "{{ (a >= b) | ternary ('test1', 'test2') }}"
  ```
- Using your own code which is correct (see the notice below)

---

Either of the above methods requires both variables used in comparison to be of the same type to give sensible results. And for a numerical comparison, they require both values to be integers.

The code from the question:

```
- set_fact:
    c: "test1"
  when: a <= b

- set_fact:
    c: "test2"
  when: b <= a
```

works properly in two cases:

- both: `a` and `b` are integers
- both: `a` and `b` are strings containing numerical value with the same number of digits

However it produces unexpected result is when:

- one of the values is string and the other integer
- the string values contain numerical values with different number of digits

Comment: I have edited the question, was bit confusing. can you please edit the answer for that