# Check if arrays are defined and not empty in ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts

I have the following code

```
- set_fact:
    MY_HOSTNAME: "SOME VALUE"
    MY_SERVER: "00.00.00.00"
- name: Get MY server
  set_fact:
    MY_SERVER: "{{ groups[MY_HOSTNAME][0] }}"
  when: groups[MY_HOSTNAME] is defined
```

In the above code, `groups[MY_HOSTNAME]` is an array. What is the best way to check that `groups[MY_HOSTNAME]` is defined and also that it is `not empty`
If it is either of that I want the value `00.00.00.00` to be assigned to `MY_SERVER`

Answer (score 55):

I don't know if it's version specific, but I'm currently running ansible-2.3.2 on RHEL6 and I had to put quotes around the group name to get it to work for me:

```
when: groups["GROUP_NAME"] is defined and (groups["GROUP_NAME"]|length>0)
```

Edit: I couldn't add this as a comment to techraf's answer because I don't have enough reputation.

Comment: Thank you... but I'm still frustrated that len(foo) (the Python way of checking length) doesn't work.

Comment: Be careful with this: `| length` works on a string as well. If the input is a string and not an array it will simply return the length of the string

Answer (score 34):

`list | length` filter returns the number of elements. If it is zero, the list is empty.

For a conditional value use `if` or `ternary` filter ([example in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42660749/2947502)).

For a composite conditional `(groups[MY_HOSTNAME]| default([])) | length`.

Comment: Is there a way to check if it is undefined and not empty at the same time?

Comment: What have you tried? What problem did you encounter?

Comment: I tried `groups[MY_HOSTNAME] is defined and groups[MY_HOSTNAME]  | length > 0`, but it does  not seem to work

Answer (score 4):

You can first check if it is indeed a list and then check if it has more than one element:

```yaml
when:
  - groups['MY_GROUP_NAME'] is defined
  - groups['MY_GROUP_NAME'] is not string
  - groups['MY_GROUP_NAME'] is not mapping
  - groups['MY_GROUP_NAME'] is iterable
  - groups['MY_GROUP_NAME'] | length > 0
```

---

You can also use `type_debug`, but it is discouraged by the [official docs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_tests.html#type-tests):

```yaml
when:
  - groups['MY_GROUP_NAME'] is defined
  - groups['MY_GROUP_NAME'] | type_debug == 'list'
  - groups['MY_GROUP_NAME'] | length > 0
```

---

Use `'MY_GROUP_NAME'`, if you directly provide the name of the group as a string or use `MY_GROUP_NAME` (without quotes), if it is a variable.

Answer (score -1):

try this one (it checks if variable is defined and if it is a iterable like list)

```
when: (groups["GROUP_NAME"] is defined) and (groups["GROUP_NAME"] is iterable)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.