# How to provide Ansible default value that includes another variable?

Tags: ansible

I want an Ansible 2.6.2 task to use the value of variable `var1` if it's set, otherwise a string containing variable `var2`. Only one of these will be set, however. If I use a simple `{{ var1 | default(var2) }}` it works, but when I try to append a string to `var2` Ansible gives an error when `var2` is undefined, even though `var1` is:

> FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'var2' is undefined\n\nThe error appears to have been in 'test.yml': line 13, column 7, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n        msg: \"Simple default: {{ var1 | default(var2) }}\"\n    - debug:\n      ^ here\n"}

Playbook:

```
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  connection: local
  vars:
    var1: "one"
#    var2: "two"
  tasks:
    - debug:
        # This works
        msg: "Simple default: {{ var1 | default(var2) }}"
    - debug:
        # This fails when var2 is undefined, even though var1 is
        msg: "Default with concatenation: {{ var1 | default(var2 + '?') }}"
```

Answer (score 6):

The error message is clear: parser requires a variable to be defined.

You can use the same `default` filter to provide default value instead of the `var2`:

```
msg: "Default with concatenation: {{ var1 | default(var2|default('') + '?') }}"
```

Comment: Thanks, this works, but is there a way to still get an error if both var1 and var2 are undefined? (Even better if it also gives an error if both are defined.)

Comment: Check `assert` module.

Comment: Sure, I could add an explicit assert, but I was hoping there was some way to do that in the templating language, like `var1 | default(var2)` would do, except that I want to add extra stuff to `var2`

Answer (score 1):

OK, I found a way that works, thanks to [another answer by techraf](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42660749/1536933):

```
{{ var1 if var1 is defined else var2 + '?' }}
```

This works if either `var1` or `var2` is defined, but if both are undefined throws an error:

> The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'var2' is undefined...

I can add a third variable to this, too:

```
{{ var1 if var1 is defined else (var2 + '?' if var2 is defined else var3 + '!' ) }}
```

Dictionary version:

```
{{ mydict.key1 if mydict.get('key1') else mydict.key2 }}
```

(`if mydict.key1` raises an error if `key1` is not in `mydict`)

Answer (score 0):

Both doing the same (don't know which is more efficient)

Variables:

```
repo: hththt
file_name: file.txt
```

Templates:

```
url: "{{ url if url is defined else repo + '/files/' + file_name }}"

url: "{{ url | default(repo + '/files/'' + file_name) }}"
```